# Make JPA persistence context recognize the changes made by bulk operations

Tags: java, jpa

JPA bulk operations, such as `DELETE` or `UPDATE`, are issued as SQL against the database. So, the persistence context is not updated to reflect the results of the operation.

For example, updating the department of all employees, the entities managed in persistence context will not have their values updated:

```
entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Employee e SET e.department = null").executeUpdate();
```

How to make the persistence context recognize the changes made by the bulk operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I have found is by invoking [`evictAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Cache.html#evictAll()) method from [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html)'s cache after a bulk operation:

```java
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

For safety purposes, it is recommended to execute bulk operations in their own transactions.

Answer (score 0):

you can reload the entity and its relationship from database using

**`entityManager.refresh(employeeInstance);`**

Note that **department** property of Employee must specify **`CascadeType.REFRESH`** on the relationship